# libarchive Complete Extractor

Tags: extractor, libarchive

I downloaded libarchive-3.3.2.zip and build it using mingw32 according to
https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions

I also set 
`LIBS += -L$$PWD/libarchive/ -larchive_static`
for static-build.

After building, I tried to extract my .zip file using examples in
https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples#A_Complete_Extractor

```
static int copy_data(struct archive *ar, struct archive *aw)
{
  int r;
  const void *buff;
  size_t size;
  la_int64_t offset;

  for (;;) {
    r = archive_read_data_block(ar, &buff, &size, &offset);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
      return (ARCHIVE_OK);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      return (r);
    r = archive_write_data_block(aw, buff, size, offset);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(aw));
      return (r);
    }
  }
}
static void extract(const char *filename)
{
  struct archive *a;
  struct archive *ext;
  struct archive_entry *entry;
  int flags;
  int r;

  /* Select which attributes we want to restore. */
  flags = ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_TIME;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_PERM;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_ACL;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_FFLAGS;

  a = archive_read_new();
  archive_read_support_format_all(a);
  archive_read_support_compression_all(a);
  ext = archive_write_disk_new();
  archive_write_disk_set_options(ext, flags);
  archive_write_disk_set_standard_lookup(ext);
  if ((r = archive_read_open_filename(a, filename, 10240))){
    exit(1);
  }
  for (;;) {
      qDebug()<<"for;;";
    r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
      break;
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(a));
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN){
      exit(1);
    }
    r = archive_write_header(ext, entry);

    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    else if (archive_entry_size(entry) > 0) {
      r = copy_data(a, ext);
      if (r < ARCHIVE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
      }
      if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN){
        exit(1);                              //A1: Program exits here.
      }
    }
    r = archive_write_finish_entry(ext);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN){
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  archive_read_close(a);
  archive_read_free(a);
  archive_write_close(ext);
  archive_write_free(ext);
  exit(0);
}
```

When I run the above code, it exits at A1.
When I debug
r = copy_data(a, ext);
I found r = -25
and  #define    ARCHIVE_WARN    (-20)

It seems something wrong with my build, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Looks like it is doing what it supposed to. Perhaps your zip is corrupt?

Comment: It is not currupted, windows explorer extract it correctly. I did not include zlib library separately. because I think zlib library is already included in libarchive_static.a